# Uploading an XML file to SAS

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, sas

I am trying to upload the stackexchange data dump in XML to SAS.
It is in this particular format.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        -<votes>
        <row CreationDate="2013-10-22T00:00:00.000" VoteTypeId="2" PostId="4" Id="1"/>
        <row CreationDate="2013-10-22T00:00:00.000" VoteTypeId="16" PostId="1" Id="2"/> 
        <row CreationDate="2013-10-22T00:00:00.000" VoteTypeId="2" PostId="1" Id="3"/>
        </votes>
```

I've tried using the default XML parsing scripts like xml and xml92 in SAS but the import has been unsuccessful.

```
libname Stackof xml 'C:\Users\abc\Documents\My SAS Files\Stackof\Votes.xml';   
libname Stack 'C:\Users\abc\Documents\My SAS Files\Stack';  
data stack.votes;    
set stackof.votes;         
run;
```

I was able to open the smaller files in Excel convert them into CSV and then upload them, but for large files(around 29 GB for the posts and votes data from stack overflow) what's the best way to go about it.

Comment: If you've actually imported the data dump into SAS, I'd love to see the code. It's something I've thought about doing before but never gotten around to doing.

Comment: @joe I was able to create an XMLmap and upload smaller files for Votes data. I used the XML map utility as you suggested. It was fairly straightforward But I haven't actually been able to do it for the large set. Even if the computer memory supports, the default SAS limitation is around 2 GB. I guess one way would be to split the large XML file and then do the upload. The other problem was with the posts data. The default SAS parser was not parsing the contents properly. Must be some special characters.

Comment: You can increase the MEMSIZE in your config file, if you have more memory available (always leave 2GB for Windows of course).  MEMSIZE, SORTSIZE, at least should be increased in most installations.

Comment: For special characters, if you have 9.3 or 9.4 you should have a Unicode version available under additional languages; that should deal with the special characters.

Comment: If you want to, post something to github I could take a peek sometime and see if I can help.

Comment: Its not a SAS limitation. Its the XMLV2 LIBNAME engine limitation. The error occurs because the XMLV2 LIBNAME engine might not release memory correctly as it parses the XML file and it eventually runs out of memory. Edit: I've just looked it up. There is a fix available for SAS 9.4. Well looks like I have to update SAS.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I have 9.4, but don't know if I have that fix or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import an XML file like this, you should first create an XML Map.  See [SAS Documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/engxml/62845/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002484891.htm) for that subject.  You can create a map by hand (I've done it multiple times before) or you can use the XML Map utility that is bundled with SAS or available for download separately.  Make sure you make the right map version for your SAS version, as later versions of SAS support more complex maps.

The map basically tells SAS what defines a dataset, what is a row, what is a column, and what datatypes each column is.  This lets SAS know what goes where, otherwise it doesn't know where to put things.

Comment: Joe - can you provide any info on how this performs for a single large file?  I've tried this method for hundreds of thousands of XML records and found it wasn't particularly efficient (seemed to have a lot of overhead).  I didn't consider throwing them all into one giant XML file and trying it that way.

Comment: @RobertPenridge The 100000 xml files certainly would have a lot of overhead.  One large file I've successfully done before with reasonable performance, for certain definitions of large; you'd have to test it on your machine and your data file I guess.  Certainly 10k-100k rows with 10-15 variables read in fine for me.